# Flutter snackbar in Hero widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-scaffold

I used to had two widgets where the first displays a list and the second is the detail page of a specific item in the list.

```
class WidgetA extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _buildAppBar(context),
      body ListView.builder(...)
  }
}



class WidgetB extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: _buildAppBar(context),
      body ....
  }
}
```

such that `WidgetA` navigates to `WidgetB`.

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WidgetB()));
```

But since I want a nice animation for the transition, I now use a Hero widget in both Widgets.

```
// Widget B
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Hero(
    tag: someObject,    
  );
}
```

But now the problem is that whenever `WidgetB` wants to display a snackbar, it is not visible there. If you would however navigate back to `WidgetA` before the snackbar would have disappeard, you can see it there.

```
ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      duration: const Duration(seconds: 3), content: Text('some text'),
));
```

I looked at the [Scaffold documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Scaffold-class.html) which states

> It is typically not necessary to nest Scaffolds. For example, in a tabbed UI, where the bottomNavigationBar is a TabBar and the body is a TabBarView, you might be tempted to make each tab bar view a scaffold with a differently titled AppBar. Rather, it would be better to add a listener to the TabController that updates the AppBar

So I also tried returning a Simple `Column` in WidgetB which is wrapped inside a `ScaffoldMessenger` but none of these solutions works... I did some lookup online and people talk about it that this is intended behaviour. But no official sources say so. How could I nonetheless display a snackbar in the detail page while still using nice Hero transitions?

Answer (score 0):

You can mimck the same effect but with bottomsheet

you can make use of this custom class I've created to make showing bottom sheet easy and accesssible from anywhere inside a project

```
class BottomSheetManager {
  bool _isBottomSheetVisible = false;
  ScaffoldState? _scaffoldState;
  String? currentMessage;
  Timer? _cancelTimer;
  PersistentBottomSheetController? _persistentBottomSheetController;

  void hideCurrentBottomSheet({bool immediately = false}) {
    if (immediately) {
      _cancelTimer?.cancel();
      _removeBottomSheet();
      return;
    }
    _cancelTimer = Timer(const Duration(seconds: 4), _removeBottomSheet);
  }

  void _removeBottomSheet() {
    _persistentBottomSheetController?.close();
    _cancelTimer?.cancel();
    _cancelTimer = null;
    _persistentBottomSheetController = null;
    _isBottomSheetVisible = false;
    _scaffoldState = null;
    currentMessage = null;
  }

  void showAlertMessage({
    BuildContext? context,
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>? scaffoldKey,
    required String message,
  }) =>
      showMessage(message: message, scaffoldKey: scaffoldKey, context: context);

  void showSuccessMessage({
    BuildContext? context,
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>? scaffoldKey,
    required String message,
  }) =>
      showMessage(message: message, scaffoldKey: scaffoldKey, context: context, backgroundColor: Colors.green, textColor: Colors.white);

  void showFailureMessage({
    BuildContext? context,
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>? scaffoldKey,
    required String message,
  }) =>
      showMessage(message: message, scaffoldKey: scaffoldKey, context: context, backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent, textColor: Colors.white);

  void showMessage({
    BuildContext? context,
    GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>? scaffoldKey,
    required String message,
    Color backgroundColor = Colors.black87,
    Color textColor = Colors.white,
  }) async {
    assert(
    (context == null) != (scaffoldKey == null),
    'you must provide either the current context or the scaffoldMessenger key to show the snack bar',
    );

    if (_isBottomSheetVisible && currentMessage == message) {
      return;
    }

    if (_isBottomSheetVisible) {
      try {
        hideCurrentBottomSheet(immediately: true);
      } catch (err) {
        debugPrint('something went wrong');
      }
      _scaffoldState = null;
      _isBottomSheetVisible = false;
    }
    currentMessage = message;

    final bottomSheetWidget = Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 60,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 40),
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: backgroundColor,
        borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
          bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
          bottomRight: Radius.circular(10),
        ),
      ),
      child: Text(message, style: TextStyle(color: textColor)),
    );

    if (context != null) {
      debugPrint('context is not null');
      _scaffoldState = Scaffold.of(context);
    } else {
      _scaffoldState = scaffoldKey!.currentState as ScaffoldState;
    }

    _persistentBottomSheetController = _scaffoldState!.showBottomSheet((_) => bottomSheetWidget);
    _isBottomSheetVisible = true;
    hideCurrentBottomSheet();
    _persistentBottomSheetController!.closed.then((value) {
      _removeBottomSheet();
    });
  }
}
```